# Deleted every node in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a song library linked list which I'm trying to delete, however when I'm testing it, my data is still there and not freed up.

```
deleteAllNodes(head);
if (head == NULL)
    printMusicLibraryEmpty();
```

I'm trying to test that if my head is now NULL, I'll print my empty message, but right now it isn't printing, which means the data isn't erased.

```
Node *deleteAllNodes(Node *head) {
while (head != NULL) {
    Node *firstNode = head;
    songNameDeleted(firstNode -> songName);
    head = head -> link;
    free(firstNode);
    firstNode = NULL;
}
return NULL;
}
```

Comment: you never change the head variable. You take a copy of the head pointer and then NULL it in the first iteration of deleteAllNodes

Answer (score 2):

In your calling function, `head` will still point to the memory location of the first node, even though your nodes are all freed. To change `head` in the calling function, you have two options:

1) Set `head = deleteAllNodes(head);`

2) Pass a pointer to `head`, and change `deleteAllNodes(Node *head)` to `deleteAllNodes(Node **head)`. In the function, you can then set `*head = NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly manipulate the head we need to pass a pointer to the caller's memory(pointer to head) instead of it's copy.
try  Node *deleteAllNode(Node **head) and while calling the function 
try deleteALLNode(&head).

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of these solutions:

- pass a var by reference:

  ```
  Node *deleteAllNodes(Node **head) 
  {
      while (head != NULL) {
          Node *firstNode = *head;
          songNameDeleted(firstNode -> songName);
          *head = *head->link;
          free(firstNode);
          firstNode = NULL;
      }
      return NULL;
  }
  ```

call of function:

```
deleteAllNodes(&head); //pass var by reference
if (head == NULL)
    printMusicLibraryEmpty();
```

- function return head value:

  ```
  Node *deleteAllNodes(Node *head) {
      while (head != NULL) {
          Node *firstNode = head;
          songNameDeleted(firstNode -> songName);
          head = head -> link;
          free(firstNode);
          firstNode = NULL;
      }
      return head;
  }
  ```

call of function:

```
head = deleteAllNodes(head); //value returned by function
if (head == NULL)
    printMusicLibraryEmpty();
```